# How to mock scan QR UI testcases without opening Camera view in Swift iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing, xcuitest

I have created application which having the Scan QR functionality, which will scan the QR and once scanning done will show the next screen.

I want to write the UI test case for scanning QR code without opening the Camera.
I have explore and found the launchArguments option, but still not satisfied my requirement.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: did you find a solution to this?